# Streamlining the implementation of a Repository Pattern and SOA

Tags: laravel, optimization, architecture, repository-pattern, soa

I'm working with Laravel 5 but I think this question can be applied beyond the scope of a single framework or language. The last few days I've been all about writting interfaces and implementations for repositories, and then binding services to the IoC and all that stuff. It feels extremely slow.

If I need a new method in my service, say, `Store::getReviews()` I must create the relationship in my entity model class (data source, in this case Eloquent) then I must declare the method in the repo interface to make it required for any other implementation, then I must write the actual method in the repo implementation, then I have to create another method on the service that calls on the repo to extract all reviews for the store... (intentional run-on sentence) It feels like too much.

Creating a new model now isn't as simple as extending a base model class anymore. There are so many files I have to write and keep track of. Sometimes I'll get confused as of to where exactly I should put something, or find halfway throught setting up a method that I'm in the wrong class. I also lost Eloquent's query building in the service. Everytime I need something that Eloquent has, I have to implement it in the repo and the service.

The idea behind this architecture is awesome but the actual implementation I am finding extremely tedious. **Is there a better, faster way to do things?** I feel I'm beeing too messy, even though I put common methods and stuff in abstract classes. There's just too much to write.

Comment: `Is there a better, faster way to do things?` You are not bound to follow the rule, if you think you can just use the concrete class without any problem then just don't use the interfaces or what ever you think is unnecessary in your context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've wrestled with all this stuff as I moved to Laravel 5. That's when I decided to change my approach ([it was tough decision](http://hawkins.io/2014/04/repositories-when-and-why/)). During this process I've come to the following conclusions:

1. I've decided to drop Eloquent (and the Active Record pattern). I don't even use the query builder. I do use the `DB` fascade still, as it's handy for things like parameterized query binding, transactions, logging, etc. Developers should know SQL, and if they are required to know it, then why force another layer of abstraction on them (a layer that cannot replace SQL fully or efficiently). And remember, the bridge from the OOP world to the Relational Database world is never going to be pretty. Bear with me, keeping reading...
2. Because of #1, I switched to Lumen where Eloquent is turned off by default. It's fast, lean, and still does everything I needed and loved in Laravel.
3. Each query fits in one of two categories (I suppose this is a form of CQRS):

   3.1. **Repositories** (commands): These deal with changing state (writes) and situations where you need to hydrate an object and apply some rules before changing state (sometimes you have to do some reads to make a write) (also sometimes you do bulk writes and hydration may not be efficient, so just create repository methods that do this too). So I have a folder called "Domain" (for Domain Driven Design) and inside are more folders each representing how I think of my business domain. With each entity I have a paired repository. An entity here is a class that is like what others may call a "model", it holds properties and has methods that help me keep the properties valid or do work on them that will be eventually persisted in the repository. The repository is a class with a bunch of methods that represent all the types of querying I need to do that relates to that entity (ie. `$repo->save()`). The methods may accept a few parameters (to allow for a bit of dynamic query action inside, but not too much) and inside you'll find the raw queries and some code to hydrate the entities. You'll find that repositories typically accept and/or return entities.

   3.2. **Queries** (a.k.a. screens?): I have a folder called "Queries" where I have different classes of methods that inside have raw queries to perform display work. The classes kind of just help for grouping together things but aren't the same as Repositories (ie. they don't do hydrating, writes, return entities, etc.). The goal is to use these for reads and most display purposes.
4. Don't interface so unnecessarily. Interfaces are good for polymorphic situations where you **need** them. Situations where you know you will be switching between multiple implementations. They are unneeded extra work when you are working 1:1. Plus, it's easy to take a class and turn it into an interface later. You never want to over optimize prematurely.
5. Because of #4, you don't need lots of service providers. I think it would be overkill to have a service provider for all my repositories.
6. If the almost mythological time comes when you want to switch out database engines, then all you have to do is go to two places. The two places mentioned in #3 above. You replace the raw queries inside. This is good, since you have a list of all the persistence methods your app needs. You can tailor each raw query inside those methods to work with the new data-store in the unique way that data-store calls for. The method stays the same but the internal querying gets changed. It is important to remember that the work needed to change out a database will obviously grow as your app grows but the complexity in your app has to go somewhere. Each raw query represents complexity. But you've encapsulated these raw queries, so you've done the best to shield the rest of your app!

I'm successfully using this approach inspired by DDD concepts. Once you are utilizing the repository approach then there is little need to use Eloquent IMHO. And I find I'm not writing extra stuff (as you mention in your question), all while still keeping my app flexible for future changes. Here is another [approach](http://fideloper.com/how-we-code) from a fellow Artisan (although I don't necessarily agree with using Doctrine ORM). Good Luck and Happy Coding!

Comment: 1) So you inject those `Repositories` and `Queries` directly in the controllers without the needing of interfaces, right? 2) When you say `commands` you mean `laravel's command bus`? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, inject them into the controller. But what I find is even better is to create a command. A command would be a DTO, plus a handler method (self-handling command). The command would be injected into your controller instead, and you would pass your request/input into it. Your command can have a bunch of public setters (totally fine for a DTO). Then you call the handle method. The handle method will be responsible for your use-case (application layer). You start a transaction, get your entity (or Aggregate Root rather) from your repo, call some behavior, then use your repo to persist it.

Comment: You can then fire events too. Grab them from the entity after you've ran behavior. Then after your transaction, loop through and fire them all. The command and handler represent a thin fascade layer over your domain (application layer in DDD).

Comment: BTW, I like to create Value Objects from the getters in the command. That way they are ready to go into the domain Aggregate root's methods. For example, your command's setters for address would be: setStreet1, setStreet2, setCity, setState, setZip. But your getter would be: getAddress.

Answer (score -2):

Laravel's Eloquent is an Active Record, this technology demands a lot of processing. Domain entities are understood as plain objects, for that purpose try to utilizes Doctrime ORM. I built a facilitator for use Lumen and doctrine ORM follow the link.

https://github.com/davists/Lumen-Doctrine-DDD-Generator

*for acurated perfomance analisys there is cachegrind.

http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html

Comment: Please don't just post a link to some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Rigth, 
Elloquent is not the approprieate way to represent Domain, there is a overhaead associated with Active Record. Try to use Doctrine, it's simply php. Another consideration of performance could done with cache grind.